# how to evaluate orthogonality of matrix in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab

I am trying to understand how matlab and decomposition methods work exactly for example for: PCA, SVD and QR decomposition.

do they just minimize an error or the decomposition are computed analytically ?

how to evaluate the orthogonality of a matrix just by one scalar value, is there a mathematic method to compute that value ?